# Run a Python pgm for multiple PDF

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, python-requests, azure-pipeline-python-script-task

I have a program exp.py which provides a yes/no result. I want to know how to run the script for multiple PDF and capture the output.

example input: xyz.pdf, abc.pdf, mno.pdf ;

1.output:

- xyz  yes
- abc  no
- mno  yes

Please advice.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SOF! From your question it's quite unclear what you are looking for? A way to read a pdf? A way to iterate code over files? Please elaborate so we can help you better.
Also, how did you try to solve this problem so far? What options did you explore?

Comment: Hey, Yes I tried some ways and found the below solution I posted as an answer. Thank you for showing interest in answering.

Answer (score 0):

$I did some research and found the below solution with Glob library. hope the below $solution helps.

```
path = "C:/Users/documents/*.*"
i=0
for file in glob.glob(path):
    pdf_file = fitz.open(file)
    print(glob.glob(os.path.basename(path))[i])
    i=i+1
```